# jQuery variable doesn't evaluate as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on creating a jQuery script with a data flow where a window variable is used to determine which path the script should proceed with. The expected path is like this:

- Initial function sets a variable, `window.QuestionSelector` to a 0, a -1, or a number
- The value of `window.QuestionSelector` at 0 means a completely new parent quiz, a -1 means a new question, and a number means an existing question is referred to.

This is the code which calls the question function

```
 $(".questionJumpLink").click(function () {
            //questionJumpLink will have a data-attribute attached if you're selecting a different question

            if ($(this).attr('data-questionid')) {
                window.QuestionSelector = $(this).attr('data-questionid');
                console.log("Question ID " + window.QuestionSelector + " requested");
            }


            if (window.QuestionSelector == -1) {
                console.log("New question request detected");
            }

    questionFunction();
}
```

This if statement, part of `questionFunction()`, is triggered despite the fact the value of window.QuestionSelector is -1.

```
 //Used when navigating between questions, not on initial load. QuestionSelector
 //is the QuestionID being requested. -1 can be set for a new question indicator
 if (window.QuestionSelector != 0 && window.QuestionSelector != -1) 
{
     console.log("Question switch, same quiz path switch");
    //Some code and handling, not vital
}
```

This if statement, directly below the above code block in `questionFunction()`, is the one I expect to be triggered:

```
 if (window.QuestionSelector != 0 && window.QuestionSelector === -1) {
     console.log("New question path");
     $("#quizQuestion").unbind();

     $("#quizQuestion").focusout(function () {
     questionField();
     console.log("Build Answers called");
     buildAnswers();
     $("input[name^=AnswerOrder]").unbind();
     enableAnswerOrderSave();
     $("[name^=AnswerID]").unbind();
     autoCheckboxOnChange();
     $("input[id^=IsValidAnswer]").unbind();
     AnswerAcDeac();
     $("input[name^=IsCorrectAnswer]").unbind();
     AnswerCorrectUpdate();
     })
 }
```

Going `==` or `===` seems to make no difference. I've verified in the debugger `window.QuestionSelector` equals -1.

Comment: Use `.data()` to get the value of `data-foo` attributes, not `.attr()`

Comment: I did write the code that way initially, but for whatever reason it didn't work consistently. I fell back to the old way, but I agree the `.data()` method is preferred.

Comment: Note that `.data()` will never update the DOM attribute - it'll read it from the DOM to initiialize the jQuery data map, but that's it. (Generally that's the way you want it to work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the variable was being set to a string, which evaluates very differently than an int.

In declaring the variable I had to modify my code using the `parseInt` function.

```
window.QuestionSelector = parseInt($(this).attr('data-questionid'));
```

Then the evaluation worked as expected.

Comment: Please specify a radix parameter when using the `parseInt` function (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).